# Password Protection for generating Excel File using ireport

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to generated excel report using ireport v3.7 with Password protection. But i am unable to do the same. As per some blogs they are saying that "JRXlsExporterParameter.PASSWORD" set the password for excel report but the "JRXlsExporterParameter.PASSWORD" set the password for protecting cells not the file.

Help me

Answer (score 2):

Excel provides several level of protection. From protecting the document by a password to protecting from adding/removing sheets or changing the size of the window. 
I don't believe any of those are doable with JasperReports 3.7 or later though, so I would log this as a bug in the Jaspersoft community.